# How to control the name of the foreign key relashionship object in EF Code First?

Tags: entity-framework

I have two entities in my EF Code first and they have a foreign key relationship.

```
   public class Condition
   {
       public int Id { get; set; }

       public string Name { get; set; }

       public bool Active { get; set; }
   }

   public class ConditionGroup
   {
       public int Id { get; set; }

       public Condition Condition { get; set; }

       public int ConditionId { get; set; }
   }
```

This is my entity map:

```
  public class ConditionGroupMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<ConditionGroup>
  {
    public ConditionGroupMap()
    {
        this.ToTable("ConditionGroup");

        this.HasKey(cg => cg.Id);
        this.HasRequired(cg => cg.Condition).WithMany(c => c.ConditionGroups).HasForeignKey(cg => cg.ConditionId).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
    }
}
```

EF will create the a foreign key object in the database with the following Name:

ConditionGroup_Condition.

The problem is that this name collides with another object in the database for reasons which are beyond the scope of this question. So I would like to ask if there is a way to change this name?

Comment: I wouldn't try to implement code first against an existing database, you are going to run into a lot of issues like this one.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing it with the Fluent API, you could do it with Data Annotations:

```
public class ConditionGroup
{
  public int Id { get; set; }

  [ForeignKey("Condition")]
  public int ConditionId { get; set; }

  public Condition Condition { get; set; }
}
```

If that doesn't end up working you could always use the `Column()` Attribute to give it whatever column name you wished.